# What causes SSH problems after rebooting a 14.04 server?

Tags: server, 14.04, ssh, openssh

Why does rebooting a server running Ubuntu 14.04 give me 'Connection refused' errors?

I see `ssh: connect to host <IP-address-here> port 22: Connection refused` but only for 14.04 and only after rebooting. I'm using 12.04 Desktop at home. How do I troubleshoot this?

---

To make the question clearer, here's what does or does not work for me:

- SSH into a fresh install of 12.04 > logout > SSH in again > works
- SSH into a fresh install of 12.04 > reboot > SSH in again > works
- SSH into a fresh install of 14.04 > logout > SSH in again > works
- SSH into a fresh install of 14.04 > reboot > SSH in again > Connection refused

The problem I'm having is unique to 14.04, and only happens after rebooting. I have several servers running 12.04 prior to this and everything still works perfectly. I've got a new server I want to use 14.04 on and I want to understand what is going wrong. Any suggestions?

---

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
sudo traceroute -p 22 -T <IP-address-here>
```

Traceroute works fine, I get a response from the server on SSH port 22.

```
initctl list
...
ssh start/running, process 23371
...
```

Looks like ssh on the 14.04 server is set to start at boot (as expected).

```
tom@Desktop:~$ ssh -vvv root@<IP-address-here>
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <IP-address-here> [<IP-address-here>] port 22.
debug1: connect to address <IP-address-here> port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host <IP-address-here> port 22: Connection refused
```

Edit: Here is the [entire syslog from a freshly created machine](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7651652/). I created it, SSH'd in & issued `reboot now` command, then got a connection refused error after waiting for it to reboot and trying to SSH in the second time. Hard reboot via hosting control panel and now SSH connection works again.

Comment: I have a similar issue, but in a very different context. It seems something has changed, but I'm unable to figure out what. I do know there are changes with udev, but I don't see exactly how it would matter, because networking seems to be working properly otherwise. Just sshd is troublesome.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad I spent 2 hours today testing this with AWS, DigitalOcean and OVH servers and can reproduce it 100% of the time. 12.04 = ok, 14.04 = no SSH after rebooting. If this were a bug I expect we'd be hearing from many others locked out of their servers! Hope I'm overlooking something but with a fresh install + single SSH login to reboot, there's not much room for human error here. Just tested it now from my 14.04 laptop (in case this was a 12.04 thing) and no change, same result. Really hope to figure this out soon...

Comment: Oh, I have many servers running sshd without any issues at all. This is the issue I referred to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/479448/moved-a-vbox-guest-to-a-physical-host-network-is-up-but-openssh-is-not-why

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Quick answer:

SSH is not the problem. The command you use to reboot is the problem: don't do `reboot now`, do `reboot` or `shutdown -r now` to reboot your system.

The command syntax ([since 13.04](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man8/reboot.8.html)) has been:

```
reboot [OPTION]...  [REBOOTCOMMAND]
```

The `REBOOTCOMMAND` never existed before. In 12.04, your `now` was just ignored but now it's being used... And it's breaking everything.

### Long answer, with my tests results and explanation:

I have a similar problem with some servers running 14.04 AND in VPS (hosted at the French OVH provider - running OpenVZ) AND when doing `reboot now` inside the server itself.

Like you I've issued the command `reboot now` from the console (logged in using SSH). A few second after I pressed <kbd>RETURN</kbd>, my session is automatically disconnected.
Like you I've never been able to reconnect to the server via SSH after issuing this command.

So, I decided to open the KVM console provided by OVH. (emulating the direct access using keyboard and screen on a physical server for this kind of virtual server).

I was able to connect to my machine and I saw that she was entering into Single User Mode, waiting for me to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to continue or to enter the root password to go into maintenance mode.
I pressed the key combination to go let the process continue and then was able to SSH into my system again. What was my surpise to see, after running `uptime`, that the uptime was not 2 or 3 minutes but yet a lot of day : `reboot now` executed inside an Ubuntu 14.04 VPS is not really rebooting but is just asking to go into Single User mode!

From this, I've learned to never ask a reboot from within my VPS but to request it from the command provided on the management interface of the hoster.

Thus there is no problem with your SSH installation. The problem is when you type `reboot now`. In fact, I tested it afterward also, if you had typed `reboot` (just the word, no option), it would have done what you were intending to do : reboot the server.

Using `reboot` with an argument (from the man page) call the command `shutdown` with the given arguments.
And indeed, if I execute `shutdown now`, I have the same behaviour : the system is not rebooted, it goes into single user mode.

**Remark:** it looks like it is the intended behaviour as the message appearing on the screen after hiting executing this command says something like :

> The system will be brought to the maintenance mode

Maintenance mode or single user mode, this represent the same, a runlevel with noting more than a shell, no network, no network processes, ...

This may be confusing, but note that the correct usage of `shutdown` is, for instance : `shutdown -h now` to halt the system now or `shutdown -r now` to reboot it now.
I wasn't aware that `shutdown now` would only bring the system into single user mode. I usually do `init S` to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for this most interesting answer! I'm going to test all this now as I am on a dedicated server (not a VPS) but I had the issue on both types - so long as it was 14.04 and not 12.04. `sudo reboot now` works perfectly in 12.04 and `uptime` corresponds to the last time I do it. Very interesting change for 14.04 though.

Comment: having exact same issue after updating server to 14.04.1, and reboot doesn't solve it.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Had to manually reboot the server. Wow, this is super annoying! Why on earth would now equate to single user mode? What a dumb choice. Why not `sudo reboot --single-user` to get that functionality???

Answer (score 3):

Another potential cause is `ufw` losing the SSH port rule configuration. This has occurred to me on at least one or two occasions, where after applying updates and rebooting, the firewall configuration was blocking me gaining access to the server. Using my hosting provider's VPS console facility allowed me to get onto the machine and diagnose the problem. Example below showing the problem (ie. no entry for port 22):

```
user@host:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
[sudo] password for user:
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
    Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
25/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
143                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
110                        ALLOW IN    Anywhere
993/tcp (Dovecot Secure IMAP) ALLOW IN    Anywhere
995/tcp (Dovecot Secure POP3) ALLOW IN    Anywhere
25/tcp (Postfix)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
465/tcp (Postfix SMTPS)    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80,443/tcp (Nginx Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
25/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
143 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
110 (v6)                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
993/tcp (Dovecot Secure IMAP (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
995/tcp (Dovecot Secure POP3 (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
25/tcp (Postfix (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
465/tcp (Postfix SMTPS (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Re-enabling the port as follows does the trick:

```
user@host:~$ sudo ufw allow ssh
Rule added
Rule added (v6)
```

Answer (score 2):

I may be late, and it may be obvious, but what worked for me was to check the configuration file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` : running the daemon with `/etc/init.d/ssh start` or any other combination showed that the service was running even though it was not, but if I launch the executable with its absolute path (in my case `/usr/sbin/sshd`) I saw that there was a "0B" appended at the end of the configuration file that caused an error when starting, removing it solved the problem.

Comment: Very useful - in my case I had typed an errant character at the beginning of the file. Very mysterious how no error is thrown if there is a problem in the config, and everything seems to start even though there is no process running.

Answer (score -1):

For my system the problem was that the ssh init script `/etc/init.d/ssh` was the only one checking for the presence of the upstart version of init.

So `/etc/init.d/ssh` doesn't start `ssh,` because it believes it will be started by `upstart`.

In my case, upstart doesn't start because of my particular configuration:

There was a correct configuration in `/etc/init/ssh.conf`, but there also was an `/etc/init/ssh.override` file containing `manual`, which means `ssh` is expected to be started manually.

This file was created by the `get-remnux.sh` installation script.

**Starting manually, or removing the `/etc/init/ssh.override` file solves the problem.**